# How do i use HTML tags in iTextSharp string

Tags: c#, html-parsing, itext

I have an iTextSharp footer template method like this:

```
public PdfTemplate footerTemplate(){
    PdfTemplate footer = cb.CreateTemplate(500, 50);
    footer.BeginText();
    BaseFont bf2 = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ITALIC, "windows-1254", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    footer.SetFontAndSize(bf2, 11);
    footer.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
    footer.SetColorFill(BaseColor.GRAY);
    int al = -200;
    int v = 45 - 15;
        float widthoftext = 500.0f - bf2.GetWidthPoint(footerOneLine[0], 11);
        footer.ShowTextAligned(al, footerOneLine[0], widthoftext, v, 0);
    footer.EndText();
    return footer;
}
```

footerTemplate() is getting string like this:

```
footerOneLine.Add("<b>All this line is bold, and <u>this is bold and underlined</u></b>");
```

And i have an other method makes strings to HTML. The method is:

```
private Paragraph CreateSimpleHtmlParagraph(String text) {
    //Our return object
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

    //ParseToList requires a StreamReader instead of just text
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(text)) {
        //Parse and get a collection of elements
        List<IElement> elements = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, null);
        foreach (IElement e in elements) {
            //Add those elements to the paragraph
            p.Add(e);
        }
    }
    //Return the paragraph
    return p;
}
```

The problem: I did not manage to use `CreateSimpleHtmlParagraph` method in the above codes. `footer.ShowTextAligned(al, footerOneLine[0], widthoftext, v, 0);` method's data types are `footer.ShowTextAligned(int, string, float, float, float);`
Could you help me how can i use `CreateSimpleHtmlParagraph` method in the above codes?
Kind regards.

Comment: Does casting `v` and the `0` to `float` work? (I.e. `footer.ShowTextAligned(al, footerOneLine[0], widthoftext, v as float, 0 as float);`)

Comment: I can not see the ShowTextAligned method's content. Because it is in itextsharp.ddl. What is the difference? There is no problem where you say. ShowTextAligned method requires string in second element. But CreateSimpleHtmlParagraph method returns paragraph. I did not manage this converting.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't understand your question correctly then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know how you're using `PdfTemplate` but you're mixing iTextSharp's text abstractions such as a `Paragraph` and `Chunk` with raw PDF commands like `ShowText()`. The abstractions ultimately use the raw commands but conveniently help you with thinks like line breaks and current coordinates that you'd normally have to manually calculate.

The good news is that there is one abstraction called `ColumnText` that works directly with a `PdfWriter.PdfContentByte` object as long as you're willing to accept that you have a fixed rectangle to draw text into.

```
//Create a ColumnText from the current writer
var ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
//Set the dimensions of the ColumnText
ct.SetSimpleColumn(0, 0, 500, 0 + 20);
//Create two fonts
var helv_n = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
var helv_b = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
//Create a paragraph
var p = new Paragraph();
//Add two chunks to the paragraph with different fonts 
p.Add(new Chunk("Hello ", new iTextSharp.text.Font(helv_n, 12)));
p.Add(new Chunk("World", new iTextSharp.text.Font(helv_b, 12)));
//Add the paragraph to the ColumnText
ct.AddElement(p);
//Tell the ColumnText to draw itself
ct.Go();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But I have learned C# for six or seven months. So I do not understand your below code. Sorry for my bad studentship. How do I integrate below given code to my PdfTemplate method where places in the question. Kind regards.